# Как запустить pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

Как запустить pg_dump, указав пароль от бд и путь к выходному файлу:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_dump.exe" -h localhost -p 5432 -d nyc -U postgres -W "1111" -f 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\backup\test_backup-20211011.sql'
```

Ошибка с передачей пароля и ошибка "не удалось открыть выходной файл". Как правильно составить команду? Использую Windows 10, СУБД postgres 12

Comment: после ключа `-W` пароль писать не нужно. Этот ключ нужен для ввода пароля в интерактивном режиме. Для пробрасывания пароля нужно использовать переменную окружения `PGPASSWORD`. С выходным файлом могут быть проблемы отсутствия нужной папки или ошибка доступа для данного пользователя. Попробуйте скрипт выполнить от имени администратора (убедившись перед этим в существовании пути для файлов дампа)

Comment: С Файлом разобрался, путь к программе необходимо указывать в кавычках, а путь к файлу без кавычек. Переменная окружения работает в винде или только в линуксе?

Comment: Кавычки нужно указывать, если в имени пути есть пробелы, не важно программу вы вызываете или путь к файлу указываете. Переменная окружения работает и в винде, и в линуксе. Проверял сегодня с утра. Ну и `-W` убрать нужно

Comment: Спасибо, еще вопросик, а как восстановить через `pg_restore` файл `.sql`? Везде пишут, что нужно через `psql`.

Comment: `psql -U %user% %database% < %sql_file%`. pg_restore служит для восстановления данных, выгруженных в бинарном формате postgres. Советую вам так не делать потому что переносимость между версиями postgres никакая.

Comment: Не советуете `pg_restore` пользоваться или выгрузками в формате `.sql`?

Comment: Советую выгрузки в формате sql и не пользоваться pg_restore потому что он не нужен.